# Make popup of dataDetectorTypes (Textview) in front

Tags: ios, ipad, textview, datadetectortypes

i have a line separator of master and detail view(ipad) and stay always appeared when touching a textview , is that a way to make always the popup in front ?thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for that you have to Create one UIView & Use like ,

//For Set Alert View

```
[[self.view superView] bringSubviewToFront: YOurCreatedView];
```

& for Dismiss Alert View

```
[[self.view superView] sendSubviewToBack: YOurCreatedView];
```

And For Animation Use below Method..

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        //     
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        //
    }];
```

or Below Method..

```
CATransform3D transform3d = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.15, 1.15, 1.15);
cell.layer.transform = transform3d;


//4. Define the final state (After the animation) and commit the animation
[UIView beginAnimations:@"translation" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];

[[self.view superView] bringSubviewToFront: YOurCreatedView];


YOurCreatedView.alpha = 1;
YOurCreatedView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
YOurCreatedView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```